# Entity Framework(Code-First Migrations): While Renaming a column do I need to make a change in the model as well?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have to rename 2 columns in my database. I am working with Code-first migrations. 
So, I added the following code to the up() an down() methods in the migration file that was created after I ran the 'add-migration migration_name' command in Package Manager Console.

**Code**

```
 public override void Up()
     {
       RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Table1", name: "oldColumnName", newName: "newColumnName");
       RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Table1", name: "oldColumnName2", newName: "newColumnName2");
     }

    public override void Down()
    {
       RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Table1", name: "oldColumnName2", newName: "newColumnName2");
       RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Table1", name: "oldColumnName", newName: "newColumnName");
     }
}
```

I did not make any change to my model since, if I ADD OR DELETE any property within the model it would add or delete those columns.

My question is after running the update-database command in Package Manager Console, will the model be itself updated or do I need to make a change and if yes, then what change and when do I make that change in the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the generated migration code, then you need to ensure that your mapping code is in sync with your database.

If you don't have mapping classes and you use convention over configuration then you need to change your model.

If you have mapping code or a separated mapping class then you need to update your mapping code to be in sync with your database.

Comment: So i should go ahead and re-scaffold by running the same migration again. Then, I run the update-database command. Will the property in the model get renamed itself after that?

Comment: It depends, if your mapping code change to support the new names or columns, your model doesn't need to change.

Comment: So, the model can have the old column names?

Comment: Can i change the property in the model after running the update-database command?

Comment: Sure. If your mapping code and your database are in sync, then everything is ok.

Comment: Do you use a separated mapping class? (derived from EntityTypeConfiguration<T>?

Comment: I have no idea if that's the case. Can you point me in some direction so that I know if that is what I have?

Comment: Sure. Look at your context, it looks like this? http://i60.tinypic.com/2dmau09.jpg

Comment: I have both of them @Jesus Angulo

Comment: Do you have mapping classes? Can you show your mapping code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the column name attribute to your model, Type is not required.
This is not required but if you run into any mapping issues this should correctly map the column.

```
[Column(“BlogDescription", TypeName="ntext")] 
public String Description {get;set;}
```

Using Code First
Name was:

```
public String FName {get; set;}
```

Changed to

```
public String FirstName {get; set;}
```

Then I run command
    add-migration UpdateColumnName
followed by command
    update-database
everything should map correctly.

Comment: I have migration files in which code for renaming column names has been added, but nowhere did I see the code that you provided. My question is how did that new column name get there? Should i change it manually by writing the new column names after running the update-database command?

Comment: If I'm just renaming columns using code first I would just go into my model and change the Field Name. Save and build, open pmc and run command add-migration ChangeNameOnColumn, then run update-database

Comment: Changing the field name in the model and running add, update migration commands will delete my previous columns and add new ones. Isn't it this way that it works?

Comment: I think that will delete my previous column and not rename it.

Comment: I think the confusion is that you are renaming a column, yet talking about a model. A Field maps to a Column, and a Model maps to a Table. So DbSet<Company> is a Model. Something like CompanyName would be a column or "Field" of the Model Company. Running migrations would only change the database not your model class. My first solution to add the column name attribute would solve your problem without the need to change any migration file manually.